# I am working on a login systemnot working

Tags: php, oracle

I am working on a login system that I would like to allow:
 - admin users to only see the admin page
 - employee users to only see the employee page

```
  <?php { include('Connection.php');
  $s = oci_parse($ora_conn, "select OPRID,OPERPSWD,OPRTYPE from OPERATOR where OPRID = 

  :uname and OPERPSWD = :upass"); 
  oci_bind_by_name($s, ":uname", $_POST['OPRID']);
  oci_bind_by_name($s, ":upass", $_POST['OPERPSWD']); 
  oci_execute ($s);
  $r=oci_fetch_array($s,OCI_DEFAULT); 
  $OPRTYPE =($r)
  if $OPRTYPE = 'Employee';
  {
  header("Location:Login_As_Employee.php"); 
  } 
   elseif($r ='Admin')
  {   

    header("Location:Login_As_Admin.php");
   }
   else
   {    
   header("refresh:0;url=sign_in.php");
    echo'<script>alert("Invalid User!")</script>'; 
    exit(); 
     } oci_free_statement($s);
     oci_close($ora_conn);
     }
     ?>
```

Comment: *"I am working on something, here's code."* - Yeah... so?

Comment: Okay... and what is the problem you are having...?

Comment: What is not working? We can't magically see that. You have to help us help you.

Comment: when i am given uname and upass it's not go to Admin and Employee page

Comment: Dude, WHY ? Use a professional system. I mean, you have no idea what you are doing, your code is horrible and 10.000 people had this idea before you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected some errors from your code, but to me it seems that it doesn't make a lot of sense in general.
You assign $OPRTYPE to $r (so $OPRTYPE and $r are the same). You then check $OPRTYPE. Later you check $r... wat?
Furthermore you assign $r to oci_fetch_array() so I automatically assume, that $r is an array (and thus $OPRTYPE aswell).
An array can't be checked that way. The check should be something like

```
if (in_array('Employee', $OPRTYPE)) {...}
```

So you see, there are some things to keep in mind. You're best off rewriting your code properly

```
<?php
include('Connection.php');
$s = oci_parse($ora_conn, "select OPRID,OPERPSWD,OPRTYPE
                           from OPERATOR
                           where OPRID = :uname and OPERPSWD = :upass"); 
oci_bind_by_name($s, ":uname", $_POST['OPRID']);
oci_bind_by_name($s, ":upass", $_POST['OPERPSWD']); 
oci_execute($s);
$r = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_DEFAULT); 
if (is_array($r) AND in_array('Employee', $r)) {
    $_SESSION['login'] = 'employee';
    header("Location:Login_As_Employee.php"); 
} elseif (is_array($r) AND in_array('Admin', $r)) {
    $_SESSION['login'] = 'admin';
    header("Location:Login_As_Admin.php");
} else {    
    header("refresh:0;url=sign_in.php");
    echo '<script>alert("Invalid User!")</script>'; 
    exit(); 
}
oci_free_statement($s);
oci_close($ora_conn);
?>
```

By the way: What about Sessions and stuff? Do your two pages 'Login_As_Employee.php' and 'Login_As_Admin.php' check if the user is actually logged in or could you just access these pages?

**Edit: Sessions**

Make sure that at the very top of EACH *.php file that uses sessions, you place the function `session_start();`
Use the above code. In your files 'Login_As_Employee.php' and 'Login_As_Admin.php' include this at the top of your file:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    die('access denied');
}
// ...
```

Your Admin file should use another check like this (depends on how you want to organize group rights)

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) OR $_SESSION['login'] != 'admin') {...}
```

Comment: thanks but when i am given uname and pass it's go to alert "Invalid User!"

Comment: Check my edits. There are several odd things in your code that can't work. I revised my code. And to better analyse your problem, we need more information. Do a var_dump($r) and tell me what it says.

Comment: it'working but when i am given Invalid User Uname and Pass then i have getting error....like

Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given

Comment: I added another check. See my edits

Comment: Thanks  Patrick Manser sir now it' working.....

Comment: Glad I could help. But still: make sure the files 'Login_As_Admin.php' and 'Login_As_Employee.php' can't be accessed directly via the browser. Use Sessions and check on these respective pages whether the session is set or not

Comment: currently i am not using session but how can use and set my session coding...

Comment: You really need to learn and practice this stuff. You can't come here and expect that you get fully working code as answers. Normally you get hints on how you can approach something. Read this article: whathaveyoutried.com. But consider yourself lucky, that I'm bored to death right now. Check my edits. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Check your if and else statements.

You're doing:

```
if $OPRTYPE = 'Employee' {...}
```

Should be:

```
if ($OPRTYPE == 'Employee') {...}
```

Check your elseif as well.

Comment: he's not even doing `if ($OPRTYPE = 'Employee')`, he's doing `if $OPRTYPE = 'Employee'` :D

Comment: Yea, that's true. I was just copying and pasting my own solution and forgot to add in his mistakes.